# pyarrow get int from pyarrow int array based on index

Tags: python, pyarrow

I am facing this really annoying issue of pyarrow not giving me the int from a list/array :((

So, I have:

```
x=pa.array([1,2,3])
x[0]
<pyarrow.Int64Scalar: 1>
```

I just want the `1` back! I tried:

```
>>> x[0].as_py
<built-in method as_py of pyarrow.lib.Int64Scalar object at 0x7f62a3abc0c0>
```

however, when I do this on strings, it works as I expect:

```
>>> y=pa.array(['1','2','3'])
>>> str(y[0])
1
```

why does this not work for int? :((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `as_py` is a method, so you need to have parenthesis to call the method:

```py
>>> x[0].as_py()
1
```

And the reason `str(y[0])` works is it's because of `__str__` method which is used when an object is passed to `str` function.